# How could I identify the first observation of every value un a column dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe like this

```
store
-----
LA
TX
NY
LA
CA
TX
LA
OR
ID
```

I need to sort them and then identify the first observation of every value in order to fund the unique values

```
store    unique
-----    ------
CA         1
ID         1
LA         1
LA
LA
NY         1
OR         1
TX         1
TX
```

I found how to identify unique values, but I need them in a column like this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first and then set `1` for duplciates by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('store', ignore_index=True)

df.loc[~df['store'].duplicated(), 'unique'] = 1
print (df)
  store  unique
0    CA     1.0
1    ID     1.0
2    LA     1.0
3    LA     NaN
4    LA     NaN
5    NY     1.0
6    OR     1.0
7    TX     1.0
8    TX     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of `np.where()` with `groupby().cumcount()` followed by `sort_values()`:

```
df['unique'] = np.where(df.groupby(['store']).cumcount() > 0,np.nan,1)
df = df.sort_values('store')
```

Returns:

```
  store  unique
4    CA     1.0
8    ID     1.0
0    LA     1.0
3    LA     NaN
6    LA     NaN
2    NY     1.0
7    OR     1.0
1    TX     1.0
5    TX     NaN
```

I added the index values in the output to show how the order is preserved via the index, but re-arranged by the `store` as you describe in the question.